# How can I reach a specific data from JSON response in flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, dart, httpresponse

I am practising flutter and I need to use a data from my response in JSON format. Here is my POST request:

```
    final response = await http.post(url,
        headers: {"Content-type": "application/json", "accept": "/"},
        body: json.encode({
          'username': id,
          'password': pwd,
          'deviceId': devid,
        }));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      check = true;
      print("OK");
    } else {
      check = false;
      print("NOT OK");
    }
    print(response.body);
  }
```

and my user data class:

```
class userData {
  String deviceId;
  String accessToken;
  String name;
  String surname;
}
userData globaluserData;
```

These are two seperate .dart files. So, in my response, I get those datas, but how can I make it like -globaluserData.name = response.name-
I did some research but to be honest I could not understand and adapt solutions to my project.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert your response into JSON and then access the data like a dictionary.

```
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  var jsonResponse = jsonDecode(response.body);

  globaluserData.name = jsonResponse['name']
} else {
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [app state provider](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple) to access a variable in the whole project. Your provider will look like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AppStateProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  UserData _currentUser;

  void setCurrentUser(UserData currentUser) {
    _currentUser = currentUser;

    //Call this whenever there is some change in any field of change notifier.
    notifyListeners();
  }


  //Getter for current user 
  UserData get currentUser => _currentUser;
}
```

You can read more from [here](https://medium.com/codechai/provider-state-management-in-flutter-d453e73537c5).